# WoL - How to start a process (batch) after Windows 10 is running?

Tags: windows-10, wake-on-lan

I'd like to start a process (batch file, exe, etc) as soon as the computer has been turned on through wake on lan, is that even possible ?

Comment: What have you tried? What research have your done? Have you looked at the Task Scheduler or Run/Run Once options built in to Windows?

Comment: Well, no, sorry. I looked around to set it all up, but I wanted to make sure it was possible before starting the next operation without knowing for sure if it would work or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Scheduled Task using the in-built Task Scheduler, and on the Triggers tab set the Begin the task to either 'At log on' or 'At startup'.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can then add Actions to run a program, be it .exe, .bat etc...